# Is there a way to use generic ids in express-resource?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Is there a way to change the default "id" in [express-resource](https://github.com/visionmedia/express-resource) from `*.<name>` to `*.id`?

Example app.js:

```
...
app.resource('projects', require('./resoureces/project')
...
```

How it is now :

```
exports.show = function(req, res){
    console.log("got id", req.params.project)
})
```

What I want:

```
exports.show = function(req, res){
    console.log("got id", req.params.id)
})
```

I want this is because I don't want the project.js file to have to know about what I wrote in the app.js file to know what the ID is.

And I know this probably will bring problems when i have multiple ids because of nesting, but it would be nice to have at the top level at least. Or a generic way to access multiple ids, for instance id, id2 id3... idX and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a look at the express-resource source I found an option not documented to define your own id per resource. If you take a look at the tests in `test/resource.test.js` you'll find a test explaining how this option is used:

```
var app = express();

app.resource('users', {
  id: 'uid',
  ...
});
```

Comment: Haven’t had time to test the solution yet but it looks extremely promising:-)
If it works I'm going to create an issue on github requesting them to document the feature.